# Color Excel header

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm writing to an Excel spreadsheet which is working fine, but I need to color the headers a dark blue color and make the font color white but im having a bit of problem figuring out how to achieve this..... this is my code so far:

```
foreach (DataColumn c in DT.Columns)
{
    iColumnCount++;
    if(iRowCount == 0)
        Worksheet.Cells[1, iColumnCount] = c.ColumnName;
    else
        Worksheet.Cells[iRowCount, iColumnCount] = c.ColumnName;

    Worksheet.Columns.AutoFit(); //Correct the width of the columns
    //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO COLOR THE HEADERS
}

foreach (DataRow r in DT.Rows)
{
    iRowCount++;
    iColumnCount = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn c in DT.Columns)
    {
        iColumnCount++;
        if(iRowCount == 1)
            Worksheet.Cells[iRowCount + 1, iColumnCount] = r[c.ColumnName].ToString();
        else
            Worksheet.Cells[iRowCount, iColumnCount] = r[c.ColumnName].ToString();

        Worksheet.Columns.AutoFit(); //Correct the width of the columns
    }
}
```

Can any one help me achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? searched for anything on google? hint: first hit on google for "C# excel cell color" is what you're looking for

Comment: yes i tried, i found some code that said i needed to create a style?

Comment: Try doing it in Excel manually while recording a macro and have a look at the generated VBA code.

Comment: Just read the first [hit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zs9xy29%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it has everything you need, don't be lazy..

Comment: I wasnt being lazy! i replied to your comment before you edited it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, its working

```
Worksheet.Range["A1","G1"].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbDarkBlue;
Worksheet.Range["A1","G1"].Font.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;
// where "A1" to "G1" is your header range
```